# How to bypass code if criteria don't match?

Tags: excel, vba

The code works when the criteria exists. I get an error when the criteria doesn't exist.

```vb
' Define constants.
Const srcName As String = "wfm_rawdata"
Const srcFirst As String = "D2" ' Location for Group
Const dstName As String = "bond_insurance"
Const dstFirst As String = "A2"  ' do not change the 'A' (entire row).


'This function will transfer rows from one worksheet to another worksheet
'  if the value = specified critiera
' Define workbook.
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook ' Workbook containing this code.

' Define Source Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim srg As Range

' Define worksheet and column am working on and 
'  getting the range of last used cell using(LastRow)
With wb.Worksheets(srcName).Range(srcFirst)
    LastRow = .Offset(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row).End(xlUp).Row
    Set srg = .Resize(LastRow - .Row + 1, 10)
End With
  
'Combine' critical cells into a range.
Dim brg As Range ' Built Range --> Range in the new sheet
Dim cel As Range ' Current Cell Range --> Range in the current sheet(rawdata)

'for every cell in group within wfm_rawdata sheet if the value = GO
For Each cel In srg.Cells
    If cel.Value = "BOND INSURANCE" Then
        ' If the range in the new sheet have nothing then
        '  add specific criteria from the group in wfm_rawdata
        If brg Is Nothing Then
            Set brg = cel
         ' if there is range in there combine the new and 
         '  old range together  using -> Union function
        Else
            Set brg = Union(brg, cel)
        End If
    End If
Next cel

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Copy and delete critical rows of Source Range.
With wb.Worksheets(dstName).Range(dstFirst)
    .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1, _
        .Worksheet.Columns.Count).clear
    Set brg = brg.EntireRow ' 'Convert' cells into rows.
    brg.Copy .Offset ' Copy. 'Offset' because range is in 'With'.
    brg.Delete ' Delete.
End With
```

How can I use a Boolean or other function to bypass the above code if the criteria doesn't exist?
For example if criteria "dog" exists then run the code and if it doesn't exist bypass the code.

I use this code to run three modules with code similar to the top code.

```vb
Sub master()
Call report1
Call report2
Call report3
End Sub
```

Comment: Probably using `WorksheetFunction.CountIf` - count the instances of the criteria, only proceed if the result is >0.

Comment: `If Not brg Is Nothing Then` - copy `brg` content over

Comment: Hi @BigBen I have 10 modules with the same code but different reports that are breaking down the sheet into categories so where do I use this code . on my calling module above that I just added

Comment: @TimWilliams Can you check the edit and let me know. So the end goal here is to run the module for example if the excel sheet I receive for example if the sheet have criteria "dog" then my code up there will run and handle this situation. But if the sheet doesn't have "dog" then my code will break down because it will run searching for "Dog" Criteria. So I am trying to Bypass my code if the criteria doesn't exist

Comment: Where would "Dog" be found if it were present, and why look for that and not "BOND INSURANCE"?

Comment: @TimWilliams Dog is just an example. The actual criteria am searching for is BOND INSURANCE in the range of the wfm raw data if its found it creates a report out of it. If its not found then the program breaks down so I am trying to bypass the Bond Insurance report 2 code if BOND INSURANCE not found in the range of wfm RAW DATA. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: You can use something like `If IsError(Application.Match("BOND INSURANCE", srg, 0)) Then Exit Sub` once you've assigned a range to `srg`

Comment: Where can I add this part in the upper code. 
 I already have Srg range assigned. @TimWilliams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One you've assigned `srg` you can use `Match()` to check whether it contains any instances of the term you're interested in:

```vb
'...
'...
' Define worksheet and column am working on and getting the range of last used cell using(LastRow)
With wb.Worksheets(srcName).Range(srcFirst)
    LastRow = .Offset(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row).End(xlUp).Row
    Set srg = .Resize(LastRow - .Row + 1, 10)
End With

'Exit if "BOND INSURANCE" is not found in `srg`
If IsError(Application.Match("BOND INSURANCE", srg, 0)) Then Exit Sub
'...
'...
```